# How to understand type inference of "f = ap min"?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I've been struggling to understand another example on type inference below,

```hs
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
ap  :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b

f   :: Ord a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
f   =  ap min

f reverse "on" -- "no"
```

How is the type of `f` inferred when `ap` is applied to `min`? Where should I look for some practical references on the topic of type inference in Haskell?

Comment: Replace `m x` with `a -> x`—functions form a monad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ap     :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
min    :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
-------------------------------------------------
ap min :: ?
```

Since `min` is the argument to `ap`, it means that we need to figure out a way to [unify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) these two types:

```
Monad m => m (a -> b)
Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

To do this, first we need to figure out what `Monad` instance (if any) applies here.  Since `a -> a -> a` is the same as `a -> (a -> a)`, the `m` type variable needs to be equated with `(->) a`.  (Note that Haskell supports currying and sections in the type system as well; just as `(+) 1` is the partial application of the function `(+)` to the argument `1`, `(->) a` is the partial application of the type constructor `(->)` to the type `a`.)

So we rewrite to this:

```
Monad m => m        (a -> b)
  Ord a => ((->) a) (a -> a)
```

This makes it easy to visualize the substitutions that we need to make in the type of `ap`:

```
m := Ord a => (->) a
a := Ord a => a
b := Ord a => a
```

But before we can proceed, we need to establish whether there exists a `Monad` instance for `(->) a`, because otherwise this is a type error.  But the following is one of the standard `Monad` instances, and it will do:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return a = const a
    fa >>= g = \r -> g (fa r) r
```

So now let's make the substitutions:

```
ap     :: Ord a => ((->) a) (a -> a) -> ((->) a) a -> ((->) a) a
min    :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
--------------------------------------------------------
ap min :: ?
```

Uncurry the types in `ap`:

```
ap     :: Ord a => (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
min    :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
--------------------------------------------------------
ap min :: ?
```

And now it's hopefully easy to see the solution:

```
ap     :: Ord a => (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
min    :: Ord a =>  a -> a -> a
--------------------------------------------------------
ap min :: Ord a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Comment: I need digest all the gems from your great answer. Thanks!

Comment: Side question: will type unification on Haskell result in one but only one correct type?

Comment: @augustss, that seems to ignore the monomorphism restriction in Report Haskell, and the limitations on let generalization in common Glasgow flavors.

Comment: @dfeuer There are some minor caveats. I regard the monomorphism restriction as a "bug", and the missing let generalization is only with certain ghc extensions.  If you want to be picky then things also break down for polymorphic recursion, GADTs, defaulting, and undoubtedly other extensions as well.  But sometimes it's better with an approximation to the absolute truth than the actual truth. :)

Answer (score 2):

your question is related to the concept of unification, which can be roughly described as the process of finding the expressions' types subjected to constrains imposed by the environment.
take a look at this excellent course/manual developed by Stephen Diehl,

> http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/#january

Chapter 5 to 8 describe what you are looking for.